# What is the degree of the extension [$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}) : \mathbb{Q}$]?

Tags: field-theory

I am trying to figure out the degree of the extension [$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}) : \mathbb{Q}$] in order to compute Gal($\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}) / \mathbb{Q}$) where $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}})$ is the splitting field of $x^4 - 4x^2 + 2.$ Not sure how exactly to compute this as $\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}$ may or may not be in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}).$ Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} \cdot \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2},$$ you can conclude that $\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}).$

Comment: ... and therefore the answer is $4$.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much.